# What is the most pythonic way to make a bound method act like a function?

Tags: python, function, methods, closures

I'm using a Python API that expects me to pass it a function.  However, for various reasons, I want to pass it a method, because I want the function to behave different depending on the instance it belongs to. If I pass it a method, the API will not call it with the correct 'self' argument, so I'm wondering how to turn a method into a function that knows what 'self' it belongs to.

There are a couple of ways that I can think of to do this, including using a lambda and a closure.  I've included some examples of this below, but I'm wondering if there is a standard mechanism for achieving the same effect.

```
class A(object):
    def hello(self, salutation):
        print('%s, my name is %s' % (salutation, str(self)))

    def bind_hello1(self):
        return lambda x: self.hello(x)

    def bind_hello2(self):
        def hello2(*args):
            self.hello(*args)
        return hello2


>>> a1, a2 = A(), A()
>>> a1.hello('Greetings'); a2.hello('Greetings')
Greetings, my name is <__main__.A object at 0x71570>
Greetings, my name is <__main__.A object at 0x71590>

>>> f1, f2 = a1.bind_hello1(), a2.bind_hello1()
>>> f1('Salutations'); f2('Salutations')
Salutations, my name is <__main__.A object at 0x71570>
Salutations, my name is <__main__.A object at 0x71590>

>>> f1, f2 = a1.bind_hello2(), a2.bind_hello2()
>>> f1('Aloha'); f2('Aloha')
Aloha, my name is <__main__.A object at 0x71570>
Aloha, my name is <__main__.A object at 0x71590>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Will passing in the method bound to a instance work? If so, you don't have to do anything special.

```
In [2]: class C(object):
   ...:     def method(self, a, b, c):
   ...:         print a, b, c
   ...:
   ...:

In [3]: def api_function(a_func):
   ...:     a_func("One Fish", "Two Fish", "Blue Fish")
   ...:
   ...:

In [4]: c = C()

In [5]: api_function(c.method)
One Fish Two Fish Blue Fish
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to clarify your question.  As Ryan points out,

```
def callback(fn):
    fn('Welcome')
callback(a1.hello)
callback(a2.hello)
```

will result in `hello` being called with the correct `self` bound, `a1` or `a2`.  If you are not experiencing this, something is deeply wrong, because that's how Python works.

What you seem to want, judging by what you've written, is to bind arguments -- in other words, [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_currying).  You can find examples all over the place, but [Recipe 52549](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52549/) has the best Pythonic appearance, by my tastes.

```
class curry:
    def __init__(self, fun, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fun = fun
        self.pending = args[:]
        self.kwargs = kwargs.copy()

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs and self.kwargs:
            kw = self.kwargs.copy()
            kw.update(kwargs)
        else:
            kw = kwargs or self.kwargs

        return self.fun(*(self.pending + args), **kw)

f1 = curry(a1.hello, 'Salutations')
f1()  #  == a1.hello('Salutations')
```

Comment: Wikipedia calls them the same thing.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying

"The practical motivation for currying is that very often the functions obtained by supplying some but not all of the arguments to a curried function (often called partial application)"